# Magento 2: Translate subject email "Your personal data has been anonymized" from GDPR?

Tags: magento2, gdpr

I have GDPR on Magento 2 store, I have tested the anonymization, and I have received an email with English content that I have to translate. 
I can translate the email content in file app/design/../Amasty_Gdpr/email/amasty_gdpr_anonymisation_notification_template.html

But how do I translate the **subject** of the email, "Your personal data has been anonymized"?
Thank you!

Comment: please check i18n directory which is exist in module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two methods you can use to do this in Magento 2.

Method 1: Override extension email template in your theme.

Copy file to below path as you've shared above.

```
app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme_name]/Amasty_Gdpr/email/amasty_gdpr_anonymisation_notification_template.html
```

And find the below content and replace it with your content.

```
<!--@subject Your personal data has been anonymized @-->
```

Method 2: Create a new email template in the email template section and change the subject for the email and assign the email template to the extension configuration.

Below is the step by step guide to create a new template in Magento 2.

> https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-customize-email-template-transactional-email-magento-2.html

**Hope it helps!!!**

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below path to update you csv file. open your respective locale and find **Subject** word.

```
app/code/Amasty/Gdpr/i18n/en_US.csv
```

than run below command.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```